# How can I switch language links to master links on a translated page?

Tags: 8, i18n-l10n, navigation

On my website currently only one content type gets translated and is therefore available in multiple languages. On this content type/page all the links (logo, menu, footer, etc.) refer to their language version of the current language.

E.g.: I'm currently on the french version of the page. The URL looks like this: "**/fr**/translated-node.html". Now all the links in the menu or footer look like this: "**/fr**/some-page.html".

But it shouldn't be like this. All the links on this page should always look like this: "/some-page.html". So without the language code at the beginning.

How can I achieve that programmatically?

Answer (score 1):

Go to admin/config/regional/language/detection/url and then you must delete the path prefix for the language, you don't need code to do this.

[image]

And save the config.

Comment: But I need the URL "/fr/translated-node.html" to stay like it is..

Comment: @elterr1ble why you want something like this?

Comment: @AdrianCidAlmaguer because the URLs "/fr/translated-node.html" are already fix in the system (production environment).

Comment: @elterr1ble I can't get the point